# Power shell to loop subfolders according to sequence

Tags: shell, powershell

I would like to use power shell to loop all subfolders and run all the files in it. But, if my root contain 3 subfolders, I would like to loop and list it accordingly to the sequence where : Subfolder C , Subfolder B and Subfolder A so that the file execution will run according to the sequence ( C-->B-->A) .

Below is my coding.

```
Get-ChildItem -path "C:\Root\subfolders\" -recurse -Filter *.sql | foreach-object -process { $_.FullName }|
   ForEach-Object {
        sqlcmd -i $_
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, get all folders of C:\Root\subfolders and foreach folder found get its files recursively :

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Root\subfolders | 
Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
Foreach-Object  {Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -Filter *.sql | Foreach-Object {sqlcmd -i $_.FullName} }
```

Comment: Hi @Shay Levy, I would like to get the file in all 3 subfolders A, B and C accroding to the sequence where files in C comes first , then B and A.

Comment: So, if a folder has 3 sub folders (a,b and c) you want the files to be executed in reverse order (c, b and then a)? What governs the order? a, b and c are real folder names?

Comment: Does this work? Get-ChildItem C:\Root\subfolders | 
Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | 
Foreach-Object  {Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -Filter *.sql | Sort-Object DirectoryName -Desc | Foreach-Object {sqlcmd -i $_.FullName} }

Comment: Hi Shay, too bad the folder's name is not alphabetically named.. Any solution for this? Eg: Folder name = Directory, Table,Data and I would like to loop files in table first. Thank you

Comment: It really depends, you got to have some logic you can use to determine the order (file name, path, expression that calculates it, etc)